# Add role to a list of names in discord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I own a discord and it has scalpers in it. I wanted to trick them with a fake role. I have all the usernames but I want to make it so I can do +scalper then a list of names. How would I do this? This is the code I have right now:

```
@bot.command()
async def scalper(ctx, *, args):
guild = ctx.message.guild
converter = MemberConverter()
role_id = 897682560119894036
role = get(guild.roles, id=role_id)
try:
    member = await converter.convert(args)
    member.add_role(role)
except:
    continue
```

If you have any ideas please let me know!

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the code you've provided here? [ask]

Comment: It will only do one member. I want to be able to do 10/20 at a time

Comment: What specifically have you tried to enable this "batch"? It's not clear what you've attempted to meet that requirement and where specifically you're getting stuck. [ask]

Comment: I've done `for members in args` that does 1 letter not the full word

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def scalper(ctx, *, args):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    converter = MemberConverter()
    role_id = 897682560119894036
    role = get(guild.roles, id=role_id)
    args = args.replace(",", "")
    x = args.split()
    for members in x:
        member = await converter.convert(ctx, members)
        print(member)
        await member.add_roles(role)
```